# Selecting A Joined Row

Tags: php, mysql

If I have these two rows:

```
Users Table      UserId  |  Username  |  Etc...
                 5       |  John      |

Avatars Table    Id      |  UserId    |  ImageName         |  ImageType
                 1       |  5         |  example.png       |  original
                 2       |  5         |  example_thumb.png |  thumbnail
```

And I have:

```
SELECT * FROM Users JOIN Avatars 
ON Users.UserId=Avatars.UserId WHERE Users.UserId = '5'
```

Do I have to add the additional:

```
AND Avatars.ImageType = 'thumbnail'
```

Or is there a way to select all and get the one I want with php (much like an array: $var['something'])??

Or is it possible to distinguish them with mysql using something like the 'AS' clause??

Comment: If I want to use both images from the query and don't want to select just one, how would I do that?

Comment: Hey thanks everybody for the answers, they all helped a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further qualifying the join with the `ImageType` condition, you will get multiple rows per user record.

**Edit:** For example

```
SELECT u.UserId, u.Username, a.ImageName, a.ImageType
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Avatars a ON u.UserId = a.UserId
WHERE u.UserId = 5

UserId    Username    ImageName            ImageType
----------------------------------------------------
5         John        example.png          original
5         John        example_thumb.png    thumbnail
```

**Edit #2:** If you want both images in one row, use this query

```
SELECT u.UserId, u.Username,
    orig.ImageName as OriginalImage, thumb.ImageName as ThumbImage
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Avatars orig ON u.UserId = orig.UserId
    AND orig.ImageType = 'original'
INNER JOIN Avatars thumb ON u.UserId = thumb.UserId
    AND thumb.ImageType = 'thumbnail'
WHERE u.UserId = 5
```

Note that this will only return rows where both image types are present for the user in `Avatars`. If you want to get a result irrespective of the existence of avatar images, use left joins.

Comment: is there a way to distinguish between them?

Comment: @mtokoly Yes, by selecting and inspecting `Avatars.ImageType`

Comment: i see, so basically i have to choose which image i want from the beginning? otherwise i get duplicate rows...

Comment: @mtokoly From your latest question edit, I think I know what you're after. See my second edit above

Answer (score 2):

If you only have two image sizes you could do

```
SELECT 
    Users.UserId, 
    AvatarsThumbnails.ImageName AS ThumbnailImageName, 
    AvatarsOriginals.ImageName AS OriginalImageName  
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN Avatars AS AvatarsThumbnails 
    ON Users.UserId=AvatarThumbnails.UserId AND AvatarThumbnails.ImageType='thumbnail' 
LEFT JOIN Avatars As AvatarsOriginals
    ON Users.UserId=AvatarsOriginals.UserId AND AvatarOriginals.ImageType='original'
WHERE Users.UserId = '5'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Users.*, O.ImageName as OriginalImage, T.ImageName as Thumbnail
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Avatars O ON Users.UserId=O.UserId AND T.ImageType = 'original'
LEFT JOIN Avatars T ON Users.UserId=T.UserId and T.ImageType = 'thumbnail'
WHERE Users.UserId = '5'
```

Use LEFT JOIN so that if either Original or Thumbnail is missing, the other is still retrieved. If both are missing, you still get a record, but with both as NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there was a way to do this in PHP, I would highly suggest letting MySQL do the filtering (by doing 'AND ..."). MySQL was built to do such tasks.